# Машинный перевод ответов на англоязычные сайты

Tags: обсуждение, лицензирование

Как известно, долгое время существует проблема сайтов, публикующих машинный перевод ответов с англоязычного Stackoverflow на русский язык. А я тут странным образом нашел пример обратной ситуации. Есть такой вопрос: [Где взять stdafx.h в Visual Studio 2019?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1031695/) А вот страница на англоязычном сайте: `https://computicket.co.za/c_plus_plus-where-can-i-get-stdafx-h-in-visual-studio-2019/`. Изучение ее содержания показывает, что это машинный перевод ответа с нашего сайта на английский язык!

> [image: translation]

Ссылку на источник они не указывают, и в качестве автора указан некий compluk, то есть лицензию они нарушают. Как вы относитесь к этому, и что с этим следует делать? Бороться, или наоборот, считать признаком успеха?

Comment: Я думаю, что такое эффективней бы было оформить вопросом на MSE. Там можно было бы к вопросу привлечь администрацию SE, а здесь пока у нас нет КМа на RU SO, мы сами по себе. Как по мне, так машинный перевод ответа, это лучше, чем ChatGPT, так что ничего особо страшного не вижу, ну кроме того что этот мусор засоряет поисковую выдачу гугла.

Comment: @aepot На MSE это скорее всего будет дубликатом <https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/>, да и там будут не очень интересны проблемы отдельного сайта. Я задал вопрос здесь, чтобы узнать мнение местных активных пользователей, так как для нас это довольно ново.

Comment: Там весь сайт, похоже, копия, а не отдельный пост отдельного юзера.